# web browser authentication in GitHub Actions for Oauth token

Tags: r, oauth-2.0, github-actions, httr

I'm trying to use GitHub Actions to query the GitHub API using an OAuth 2.0 token through an R script.  It works fine on my local machine when I run the code, where a browser window pops up indicating "Waiting for authentication in browser..." that I can manually close.  When run through GitHub Actions, the workflow hangs at the "Waiting for authentication in browser..." since it's on a remote machine.

I'm using a custom R script with the httr library.  The API credentials are stored as secrets for the repository I'm trying to query.

```
library(httr)

gh_key <- Sys.getenv('GH_KEY')
gh_secret <- Sys.getenv('GH_SECRET')

# setup app credentials
myapp <- oauth_app(appname = "data-in-r",
                   key = gh_key,
                   secret = gh_secret)

# get oauth credentials
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints('github'), app = myapp, cache = F)

# use api
gtoken <- config(token = github_token)

# get list of remote files in data folder
req <- GET("https://api.github.com/repos/tbep-tech/piney-point/contents/data", gtoken)
```

When the script is run through GitHub Actions, it looks like as below, where I had to manually cancel the workflow since it was hung at the browser step.

[image]

Is there a workaround for skipping the browser step so it will run on GitHub Actions? The offending repo is [here](https://github.com/tbep-tech/piney-point-analysis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the 3-legged variant of OAuth2.0 (aka "web-application flow") in a headless environment like Github Actions.

If you want to use OAuth (I list other possibilities below), then you need to utilize what gitlab calls the "device-flow". See [github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps#device-flow).

In this flow, there is no redirect to a given URL, so the app does not need a browser window. Instead it displays a code to the user. The user must the enter that code on a fixed URL (https://github.com/login/device). As soon as this is done, the app can request the authentication token. (So the app must keep polling until the user has entered the code).

Unfortunately, `httr` does not have nice wrapper functions for this variant, so you have to do the calls yourself. It can work like this:

```
library(httr)



app_id <- "*redacted*"


r <- POST("https://github.com/login/device/code", 
          body = list(
            client_id = app_id,
            scope = "user repo delete_repo" #Scope must be given! https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps
))


device_code <- content(r)$device_code

print(paste0("Enter the code  ", content(r)$user_code, "  at ", content(r)$verification_uri))


## NOTE: In reality this request has to run in a loop, until the user has entered the code und the request succeeds.
##       For the demo we can execute it manually after the code has been entered.
r <- POST("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", 
          body = list(
            client_id = app_id,
            device_code = device_code,
            grant_type = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"
          ))

token <- content(r)$access_token

## create and delete a private testrepository to check if everything worked
r <- 
  POST("https://api.github.com/user/repos",
       add_headers(Authorization = paste("token", token)),
       body = list(name = "testrepo",
                 private = TRUE,
                 auto_init = FALSE), 
       encode = "json")


r <- DELETE(paste0("https://api.github.com/repos/", content(r)$full_name), 
       add_headers(Authorization = paste("token", token)))
```

I have seen that there is `httr2`, and that it offers convenience functions for this flow. I have however never used it and do not know if it already works reliable. See [here](https://httr2.r-lib.org/reference/req_oauth_device.html).

Since this flow still requires user interaction, you may be better of with one of the following variants (I do not know if they fit your use case.):

1. **Basic Auth:**
   You can define what github calls a "personal access token" beforehand. With this token you can authenticate without further interaction. Creation is described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token). In R you can use it most easily together with `httr::authenticate`.
2. **GITHUB_TOKEN:**
   Github automatically creates special secrets specifically Github Actions. These can be used to execute actions in the containing repository. For more info see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow).

Comment: Excellent, great info for troubleshooting. I had a suspicion that what I needed was not possible with OAuth2.0.