# Store oauth token as a github secret

Tags: r, github, oauth, github-actions, httr

I use the `R` package [`httr`](https://httr.r-lib.org/) to authenticate myself at an oauth endpoint ([strava](https://developers.strava.com/)) using `oauth_endpoint()`, `oauth_app()` and `oauth2.0_token()` (Step 1).

```
# Step 1: Genrate oauth token

strava_endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(
  request = NULL,
  authorize = "authorize", 
  access = "token",
  base_url = "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/oauth/"
)

myapp <- oauth_app(
  "strava", 
  key = 0000000,        # <- my key
  secret = "mysecret"   # <- my secret
)

mytok <- oauth2.0_token(
  endpoint = strava_endpoint, 
  app = myapp,
  scope = c("activity:read_all"),
  cache = TRUE
)
```

This last function requires me to authenticate via browser and permit the requested scope, which is then cached as a token `.httr-oauth`. After doing this once, I can use this token file with `readRDS()` to use `GET()` via the strava API (Step 2)

```
# Step 2: Use the file ".httr-oauth" got use the API (GET)
mytok <- readRDS(".httr-oauth")[[1]]

GET("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete", config(token = mytok))
```

```
Response [https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete]
  Date: 2022-03-09 07:53
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 650 B
```

This works fine locally. However, I would like to pass this token to a [github action](https://github.com/features/actions) to `GET()` on my behalf. In other words, I want to do Step 1 locally and use the generated token (file `.httr-oauth`) in a Github Action (Step 2)

But, [since this token is a secret and should be added to `.gitignore`](https://httr.r-lib.org/articles/secrets.html), I don't know how to authenticate the github action.

I thought I could add `.httr-oauth` as a [github secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets), but it seems to be an encrypted file.

Is there a different way to authorize a github action to `GET()` my data via an API (e.g. strava)?

Comment: [this](https://svrooij.io/2021/08/17/github-actions-secret-file/) looks promising

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68918609/4139249) as well

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems to be an encrypted file.

The "[Using encrypted secrets in a workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow)" shows you should be able to retrieve the value of that secret:

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Hello world action
    with: # Set the secret as an input
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
    env: # Or as an environment variable
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.SuperSecret }}
```

It is then a variable (or environment variable), with its value (not encrypted) you can use in the rest of your workflow.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether I understand. Are you saying: 1) encrypt `.httr-oauth` using `gpg` and a passphrase 2) push to github 3) add passphrase (from step 1) to the repo 4) decrypt `.httr-oauth` and 5) import the decrypted file using `readRDS` ?

Comment: @Ratnanil you should be able to register your value (in clear) as a GitHub secret in your GitHub repository (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository). Once registered, your GitHub action can retrieve it. No need to encrypt it further.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I still don't understand. How do I get my value in clear from my `.httr-oauth` token (which is a file)?

Comment: @Ratnanil Is that file a static content (which never changes?) or a generated one which can change  on each execution?

Comment: @Ratnanil In the later case, you can create/update a secret with the GitHub API: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-or-update-a-repository-secret

Comment: Its a static content which never changes, and which I can only generate locally (since the function `oauth2.0_token()` invokes the browser where I need to authenticate myself)

Comment: @Ratnanil So you can register manually on the repository as a secret.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242783/discussion-between-ratnanil-and-vonc).